# Why does my SPARQL query only return buitlin predicates?

Tags: sparql, owl

```
SELECT ?predicate (COUNT(*)AS ?frequency)
    WHERE {?subject ?predicate ?object}
    GROUP BY ?predicate
    ORDER BY DESC(?frequency)
    LIMIT 50
```

I want to find and order most frequent predicates. I am interested in the frequency of predicates defined by myself, but not all these builtins as below:

```
rdf:type
hashcode
sourceOntology
rdfs:subClassOf
rdf:first
rdf:next
...
```

None of my predicates appear. How to display user defined predicates?

Comment: Without knowing **which API** you use and **how you load the data** and **how you run the query** it's impossible to give any useful advice. The query itself is correct, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I am using Protege, querying with SPARQL Query tab. The ontology is the one I am creating in Protege Desktop.

Comment: Protege 5.1? And your ontology contains instance data? Are you sure that the whole resultset is shown? Does it return expected data if you use `SELECT DISTINCT ?predicate WHERE {?subject ?predicate ?object}`?